# Button is not showing correctly if it's after spinner in horizontal linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have an axml layout for android in xamarin with this code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20px"
    android:id="@+id/space1" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:paddingLeft="25px"
        android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:paddingRight="15px" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="15px"
        android:id="@+id/spinner" />
    
</LinearLayout>
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25px"
    android:id="@+id/space2" />
<EditText
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="long text"    
    android:inputType="textLongMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/editText1" />
```

And it's working.

[layout before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hgwS.png)

But I need the button to be in the upper-right corner, so I tried to place it after spinner in the same horizontal linearlayout (here's a code of a nested linearlayout only):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:paddingLeft="25px"
        android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:paddingRight="15px" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="15px"
        android:id="@+id/spinner" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And after that change layout looks weird:

[layout after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LFdf.png)

What's wrong here? Why is THIS happening to button? How can I fix this?

EDIT:
The above layout code was a fragment. Here's a code of activity where I use this fragment:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This layout is caused by the height match parent in the spinner, because it takes all the space and dont let any place to the button. If you adjust it with a fixed size like 150dp or with a wrap content it will work.